# Windows 7 Home: how to configure a logon script

Tags: windows-7, login

On Windows 7 Professional one can right-click the user in the *Computer Management*'s *Local Users and Groups* to set the Logon script on the *Profile* tab. Unfortunately, Windows 7 Home Premium does not (seem to) have the *Local Users and Groups* in the *Computer Management*. How to configure the logon script on Windows 7 Home Premium.?

Comment: In a standalone system, is there any advantage in configuring a logon script over just putting it in the Startup folder?

Comment: The advantage is that the script will be loaded very early, e.g. before launching other applications. This is very useful to mount encrypted partitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summary for what I did to resolve this issue:

- I've created a script in `C:\Windows\System32\repl\import\scripts\<username>.bat`
- invoked `net user <username> /scriptpath:<username>.bat`

Because Windows 7 Home did not wait until this script had been finished and continued to load other applications, I also needed to create a `DWORD` entry named `RunLogonScriptSync` at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` in the registry setting the value to `1`.

Comment: Is there a way to reverse this command? In other words turn off a script you assigned to a user profile?

Answer (score 8):

You're right, this MMC snap-in is disabled unless you have at least Windows 7 (or Vista) Professional.

You should be able to configure user properties using the [net user](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771865%28WS.10%29.aspx) command:

```
net user UserName /scriptpath:logon.bat
```

The script location:

> Local logon scripts must be stored in
>   a shared folder — or subfolders of the
>   shared folder — named Netlogon. If
>   this folder does not exist by default,
>   you must create it. To specify a logon
>   script that is stored in a subfolder
>   of the Netlogon folder, precede the
>   file name with the relative path to
>   that folder. For example, to assign
>   the Startup.bat logon script that is
>   stored in
>   \ComputerName\Netlogon\FolderName to
>   a local user, in Logon script type
>   FolderName\Startup.bat

Comment: Where is the directory "\ComputerName\Netlogon\FolderName" located?

Comment: @mklhmnn: Wherever you want it. The example given is for a domain, with one server holding all scripts; domain controllers have a share `\\servername\Netlogon` for this purpose. If you give a relative path, it will be looked for in the DC's `Netlogon` share. (Behavior unknown for standalone systems.) But you can give an absolute path, e.g. `C:\WINDOWS\Misc\logon.cmd`.

Comment: Wherever you want - for example, create a folder c:\logon and share it as Netlogon.

Comment: @grawity using `/scriptpath:path` You can't use an absolute path.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is the way to do it, if you want your script running early in the system startup, or need the script to run synchronously - that is, the normal logon process will continue only after your script has completed (watch out, it can slow down logon, use it only if you need it).

Note: I'm not sure if the *scripts* mentioned above can be an `.exe` file or not, but in the method I will describe any executable can be used.

Another way to do, which has some extra flexibility, is using the `Task Scheduler`. From the start menu, type Task Scheduler and run it (or run `taskschd.msc` from `Run` dialog or a shell). Select `Task Scheduler Library` in the tree view. If you want, you can create a special subfolder for your programs, but this is not necessary. Click `Create Basic Task...` (wizard) or `Create Task...` in the `Actions` panel on the right side.

I will explain how to use `Create Task...`.

- In the `General` tab, fill out a descriptive name and, optionally, a description for your task.
- In the `Triggers` tab, click `New...`, set `Begin the task` to `At log on`. Check the `Specific user` combobox, make sure your username is selected (you can use `Any user` if you want the program to run when any user logs in). If you don't want your script to slow down the log in process, you can choose to run it after a delay - click `Delay task for` checkbox and type in the time (e.g. `30 seconds`). Click ok to create the trigger.
- In the `Actions` tab, click `New...`, choose your program (or script) using `Browse...` or type in the full path into `Program\program`. If the program is in your %Path%, you can just use `program`. You may specify any arguments to pass to the program in `Add arguments`. You may specify the working directory for the program in `Start in`. You can use any type of script the local computer supports; if a script type is not registered with Windows, you can still run it by specifying the script interpreter as the program. E.g. use `C:\path\to\python.exe` as the program, and `C:\path\to\script.py some_arguments` as arguments. Click ok to create the action.
- In the `Conditions` tab, you probably want to uncheck the `Start the task only if the computer is on AC power`.
- In the `Settings` tab, there is no need to change anything.

Click ok to create the scheduled task. If you want to edit it later, just select `Task Scheduler Library` in the tree view, find your task in the list (at top part of the window) and double-click the task.

See the [Task Scheduler reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721871.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I’m using Win 7 Premium Home on a standalone system and wanted to run a logon script to mount an encrypted volume. Searching the net gave only complicated results (gpedit, registry update).
My solution is very simple: I created on C: a folder (with a name whatever you want) and put my script into it. This folder must be shared with the share name “Netlogon”
It works! At least on my local system.

Answer (score 1):

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

If you get an error like this when running the **net user** command, make sure you run **CMD** as adminisitrator (use right click and select "Run as administrator")!

Answer (score 1):

You can also just create a task using task scheduler and setting the trigger to run the script at logon.

Comment: This answer could be improved by including procedures and steps involved to configure a script to run in task scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You still use UI to configure logon script in Windows 7

Open `"Control Panel" -> "User Accounts" -> "User Accounts" -> "Manage User Accounts" -> "Advanced" -> "Advanced"` to access "Local Users and Groups (Local)" MMC snap-in.

or just launch from cmd shell: `mmc.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\lusrmgr.msc computername=localmachine`